# How to parse strace in shell into plain text?

Tags: shell, parsing, escaping, strace

I've trace log generated by [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) command like on running PHP by:

```
sudo strace -e sendto -fp $(pgrep -n php) -o strace.log
```

And the output looks like:

> `` 11208 sendto(4, "set 29170397297_-cache-schema 85 0 127240\r\n\257\202\v\0?\0\0\0\2\27\10stdClass\24\7\21\3cid\21\6schema\21\4d\37ata\25\n\247\21\5block\24\6\21\6fields\24\f\21\3bid\24\2\5\21\4type 0\37erial\21\10not null\5\21\6module\24\4\16\7\21\7va\37rchar\21\6length\6@\16\t\5\21\7default\r\21\5de\2lta@\5\16\v\16\f\6  \35\7\16\r\21\0010\21\5t \207C\30@6\2\16\r\r n\4tatus@0\4\21\3int/\7\6\0\21\4size \222\finy\21\6weight\24\3 ;\0\22\300 \6\6region@8\340\5P\5custom\27\300,\17\16\23\16\24\21\nvisibility\340\t\34\7\5pages\24\2 \205\3\4tex@\206 \261\1it \365\0\5\240\0\377y\10\r\21\ftransl!N\2ble %\1ca!a\340\3Q\0\1n\31\vprimary key\24\1\6\0\16\6\21\vunique@\21\ts\24\1\21\3tmd\24\3 \31\0\20 2\v\n\6\2\16\16\21\7index \210\10\1\21\4list\24\5\240\36\0\21 \36\10\26\6\3\16\25\6\4\16\n \1\6\4\21\4name \7\0\na\317\2_ro\252\0\5!$\0\n \3\341\2\23\0\16\340\0\16A\214\2\21\3r!\354@ \v\22\21\10unsigned\5@\332\0\36\213\0\n \213\0\16 l\6%\16!\24\1\16%\271\0%@p\5\16#\16$\21\f\200l\241b@n\2\4\16\6M\2\10\16&@E\4\21\4bod\201_\5\32\16\t\4\16\23B\\\2g\16\34 \30\3info .\0\7a\255\0\200@q!L\5\6forma\201\332B/!d\2\4\16\37 y\0*y\0 \225a;\240\201\2'\21\van\0_\207\200\2\5\16\1\340\0U =@U\1\16\3@\222 \212\2lob@O\n\23\16)\21\6expire@\30\342\0\26\7\21\7create\241\17< \25\0\n\203\1\"\177\0dY\0\22 \305\5\5small\240!a\32\0.\230\0.\240\240\0\1\240\240\3,\21\vb S\2kpo\"\313\2s\24\6!\220\2\t\21\2\241q\0\10 ?\4\21\tno  \213\6ort\5\21\fm\";\3ine_A\313\232\241\3\2\5\16#\340\4\16!\345\340\0U\223\340\0'AC\4sourc\202\202\340\3\27\0\v\200\27\0_C\326\340\0074\1\16\21_\240\363\2\1\16\25\340\3\16\r\0\21\vmultipliers\31\0- \223\1\21\t\341\0\30B-\0\1!\10\0003a\253\0005\v\0005ac \327Dz\"\364 \20\0\10 \6\0 @\333\r\0165\16\36\0163\21\nidenti$x\nr\0166\21\vadmin_ce\10\21\5label\21\f\244H\6 hook\21\23\240\r\0_\340\1\375\fs\21\3api\24\4\21\5own F\0062\16C\16B\21\17 H\5imum_v \260$\25\7\6\1\21\17curr m\340\1\22!\242\0002\"\305\0022\21\20\340\1N\5_groupa\247\2\6\0163\352\0\10 \352\2\0164\5 \325C%\341\0P\341\5\220\1\0162aQA\26\4\16:\5\21\17\201\321\1 c\"$\5back\21#\340\7b\0_\200!\340\3\311\1\16\7C\340\0a!\312\1\no \300#\240!&}\241\237\0\0\242e\341\4n\5\16;\24\10\16< \7\2=\21\35\340\1m\0\320\0 \342\3XAz\v\16>\16G\16?\16@\16A\21\30\341\tT\201\5\1\21\22\200\243\0 B0\6 string#o\4toolsbD\1\16C \260\0D!D\4C\16L\16E!P\0F \3\201T\16G\21\21ckeditor_set%\266\0gE\323\0\5%Q\0# 4@\345!)\"w#\372\1\21\10\340\0!\0\1 \31\0\32\240\334\4#\16\n\21\10\300D \r\2O\21\25\300\r\6_input_\244+\340\16V\1\16+ \31\340\4h X\0\2!;\0# \245\0+ \247\0Q T\7R\21\26comme#/\0_%\266\2cko W\3pane ;\4\5\24\10\21\7@\v\0_\243\257\301\231\1\21\4F\35 !\340\1\22F\323\0021\21\10\"\311'B\0e@\223A\254&f`\346\"~\6\vcollap&q%\227\340\6\35\2\0\21\t\240\35\344\1a\3009\0\0#\212\300.\0001\200L$\247\1enFl\344\0\216\300,\0\1G\5\3view\340\0002\300\177 \372\0\1 K\0T!"..., 8196, MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_MORE, NULL, 0) = 8196 ``

It sounds like these are represented by ordinary [C escape codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25708951/55075).

I've tried to decode them in shell by `printf` like:

```
while read line; do printf "%s" "$line"; done < <(cat strace.log | head -n2)
```

but it failed (looks like it doesn't make any sense):

> `` 11208 sendto(4, "set 29170397297_-cache-schema 85 0 127240rn257202v0?00022710stdClass247213cid216schema214d37ata25n247215block246216fields24f213bid2425214type 037erial2110not null5216module244167217va37rchar216length6@16t5217defaultr215de2lta@516v16f6  35716r210010215t 207C30@6216rr n4tatus@04213int/760214size 222finy216weight243 ;022300 66region@83405P5custom27300,171623162421nvisibility340t3475pages242 20534tex@206 2611it 365052400377y10r21ftransl!N2ble %1ca!a3403Q01n31vprimary key2416016621vunique@21ts241213tmd243 31020 2vn621616217index 210101214list24524036021 3610266316256416n 164214name 70na3172_ro25205!$0n 3341223016340016A2142213r!354@ v222110unsigned5@3320362130n 213016 l6%16!24116%2710%@p516#16$21f200l241b@n24166M21016&@E4214bod201_53216t41623B\2g1634 303info .07a2550200@q!L56forma201332B/!d241637 y0*y0 225a;2402012'21van0_207200251613400U =@U1163@222 2122lob@On2316)216expire@303420267217create24117< 250n2031"1770dY022 30555small240!a320.`2300.240240012402403,21vb S2kpo"3132s246!2202t212241q010... ``

Is there any better way to parse the output of `strace` command to see plain strings passed to `recvfrom`/`sendto`?

Ideally it is possible to print printable characters including new lines (`\r\n`), but cut-off NULLs and other non-printable characters?

Comment: The reason `strace` escapes them is that they're binary data , not plain text.

Comment: What do you want the output to be for something like `\0\0\0\2\27\10` ?

Comment: I'd like to extract some meaningful text from the dump and its context. Whatever it is, but escaped characters making it unreadable. This is most likely communication between `memcached`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem why `read` doesn't work, because shell is already escaping the characters, so the string is doubled escaped, therefore `\r\n` is printed as `rn`.

To [ignore escaping of characters by shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23621615/55075), you can use `read -r` which allow backslashes to escape any characters (so they're treated literally). Here is example:

```
while read -r line; do printf "%b\n" "$line"; done < strace.log | strings
```

Since it's a binary data, above example also includes `strings` command to display only printable strings.

Strace also support printing all strings in hex when `-x` is specified, but it'll work the same.

---

Here is the version to parse `strace` output in real-time:

```
while read -r line;
    do printf "%b\n" "$line" | strings
done < <(sudo strace -e recvfrom,sendto -s 1000 -fp $(pgrep -n php) 2>/dev/stdout)
```

---

Further more `strings`, can be replaced by more specific filter using `grep`, to get only what is inside double quotes:

```
grep -o '".\+[^"]"' | grep -o '[^"]\+[^"]'
```

however this may still print binary formats.

To avoid that, lets simplify the whole process, so lets define the following formatter alias:

```
alias format-strace='grep --line-buffered -o '\''".\+[^"]"'\'' | grep --line-buffered -o '\''[^"]*[^"]'\'' | while read -r line; do printf "%b" $line; done | tr "\r\n" "\275\276" | tr -d "[:cntrl:]" | tr "\275\276" "\r\n"'
```

where:

- `grep -o '".\+[^"]"'` - select double-quoted string with quotes
- `grep -o '[^"]*[^"]'` - select text within the double quotes
- `while read -r line` - store each line into `$line` and `do` some action (`help read`)
- `printf "%b" $line` - print line by expanding backslash escape sequences
- `tr "\r\n" "\275\276"` - temporarily replace `\r\n` into `\275\276`
- `tr -d "[:cntrl:]"` - remove all control characters
- `tr "\275\276" "\r\n"` - restore new line endings

then the complete example to trace some command (e.g. `php`) can look like:

```
strace -e trace=read,write,recvfrom,sendto -s 1000 -fp $(pgrep -n php) 2>&1 | format-strace
```

---

Check for similar example: [How to view the output of a running process in another bash session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275826/21471) at Unix.SE

Comment: Doesn't work correctly for me. E.g. `\0374` gets decoded as `fc` by `printf`, while in reality it's `1f34`